# Mongodb installation in windows 10

Tags: mongodb, windows-10

Everytime when i try to run mongodb it throws this error [image]

Also , i installed and unzip vcruntime 140 and copy paste the file vcruntime inside the system as per solution but it did not work for me.

Comment: Did you install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)? Did you install MongoDB with `.msi` file or from `.zip`? Note, MongoDB runs only in 64-bit.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes Install mongodb .zip. I have a 64-bit.

Comment: Try to use the .msi file, this should include all dependencies.